# Why cant i import turtle nor turtle.Screen in VS - Python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I've been stuck on this for ages not getting response. I've already tried to do the commands like `import turtle, wn = turtle.Screen()` but none of these works on Visual studios for me.

Once I type these commands, it doesn't say anything in the "problem" or output bar, but nothing just happens. Like No turtle screen pops up or anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working turtle program. 
Test if your IDE works with that - with inputs of 50, 4 and 60 you get the following output:

[image: demo output]

```
import math
import turtle

def squareFromCurrPosAndRotationAsCenter(bob, s):
    """Starting from current position and rotation, draw a square of sidelength s.
    End on same position and rotation you began with."""
    # goto first side
    bob.penup()
    bob.forward(s/2)
    bob.pendown()
    # draw a half side
    bob.right(90)
    bob.forward(s/2)
    # draw three full sides
    for k in range(3):
        bob.right(90)
        bob.forward(s)
    # draw last half side
    bob.right(90)
    bob.forward(s/2)

    # goto back to origin
    bob.penup()
    bob.right(90)
    bob.forward(s/2)
    # turn back in original direction
    bob.right(180) 


def getInt(text, default): 
    """Try to parse input to int, return default if not possible"""
    try:
        return int(input(text))
    except:
        return default

def symetricSquares():
    # Get user input or (when error) use default
    size = getInt('Enter size for top square: ', 50)
    num_squares = getInt('Enter the amount of squares: ', 4)
    angle = getInt('Enter increase of starting angle: ', 60)

    # Create a turtle
    bob = turtle.Turtle()

    bob.speed(max(5,(num_squares * 360/angle)//10)) 

    # outer loop changes starting angle
    for startAngle in range(0,360-angle+1,angle):
        bob.setheading(startAngle)

        # we use a list comp to create the desired square sizes
        # you could also do [size, size*2, size*3, size*4] if 
        # you want always 4 circles

        for s in [size*(n+1) for n in range(num_squares)]:
            squareFromCurrPosAndRotationAsCenter(bob, s)

    turtle.mainloop()


def main():
    symetricSquares()

main()
```

If this does not work you have to see if you are missing packages.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal sample, works just fine

```
''' sample.py '''
import turtle

s = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.forward(100)
s.exitonclick()
```

after running, you will get

```
> python3 ./sample.py
```

[image]

Comment: Oo.oO the thing is that it doesnt work when i type in these commands like nothing happens. U know why ?

Comment: @BjorneX Can you try it from command line instead of Visual Studio? In case of errors like this, it's good to reduce possible sources of issues and start as close to interpreter as possible.

Comment: Oo.oO Now ive downloaded it all, but once i type in the commands, still no window pop up or anything